# When updating the state in react, how should state be handled if elements are simultaneously seeking to access and alter its data?

Tags: reactjs, json, typescript, react-hooks, yaml

***Problem:* I'm not able to add new keys and/or values either in the JSON editor or the YAML editor if they both share and update the same state.**

Parent Component that passes the JSON data to Child Component via props

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Editors from './Editors';

const jsonData = {
  name: 'name',
  email: 'email',
  phone: [123, 234, 345],
  location: 'location',
  country: 'country',
  show: true,
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Editors jsonData={JSON.stringify(jsonData, null, 4)} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Child Component that receives the JSON data via props.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import YAML from 'yaml'; // ---> official YAML package
import { load } from 'js-yaml'; // ---> official YAML package for JavaScript
import Editor from '@monaco-editor/react';

export interface Iprops {
  jsonData: string;
}

function Editors(props: Iprops) {
  const [data, setData] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    setData(props.jsonData);
  }, [props]);

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div>
        <h5>JSON:</h5>
        <Editor
          height="300px"
          defaultLanguage="json"
          value={data}
          onChange={(val) => setData(val)}
          theme="vs-dark"
        />
      </div>

      <div>
        <h5>YAML:</h5>
        <Editor
          height="300px"
          defaultLanguage="yaml"
          value={YAML.stringify(load(data))} // ---> load will parse the JSON data to plain object
          onChange={(val) => setData(JSON.stringify(load(val), null, 4))}
          theme="vs-dark"
        />
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

export default Editors;
```

***GOAL:* I should be able to maintain the state, add new keys and values, change already-existing keys and values, and update both the JSON and YAML editors with the appropriate conversions.**

stackblitz link to see the problem in action: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-mmrra6?file=Editors.tsx,App.tsx

Answer (score 0):

You have to handle possible errors somehow

I would add change handlers like:

```
  const onChangeJSON = (text) => {
    try {
      const obj = JSON.parse(text);
      setData(obj);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  };

  const onChangeYml = (text) => {
    try {
      const obj = load(text);
      setData(obj);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  };
```

Notice that I've changed your state type to object

```
export interface Iprops {
  jsonData: object;
}
```

```
const [data, setData] = useState({});
```

[Full example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-zrpguz?file=Editors.tsx)

Comment: Before I ever brought up this problem, I already knew your strategy. The issue is that the YAML editor is immediately updated when a new key and value are added to the JSON editor. The value will then be null in the YAML editor if you add a new key followed by a colon (:), and this is updated in the JSON editor as well. Every new key is further given a null value by the YAML editor.